# Autoplay in slider with js

Tags: javascript

```js
let left = document.querySelector('.left');
let right = document.querySelector('.right');
let img = document.querySelector('.imgs');
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');

let index = 0;


function rightimg() {
  right.addEventListener('click', function () {
    index++;
    if (index > imgs.length - 1) {
      index = 0;
    }
    img.style.transform = `translateX(${-index * 500}px)`;
    console.log(img);
  });
}

// setInterval(rightimg, 2000);

left.addEventListener('click', function () {
  index--;
  if (index < 0) {
    index = imgs.length - 1;
  }
  img.style.transform = `translateX(${-index * 500}px)`;
  console.log(img);
});
```

Hi friends,
I want to make autoplay image in this slider but setInterval is not working,
can you say what is wrong in here?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your function adds an eventlistener but it will only work when there will be an event(which is click in this case)

You can use swiperjs, it has many types of features and framework/library implentations. https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api